# Where can I host my PHP files

Tags: php, android, sql

I'm not sure if I used the right term "Where can I host my PHP files" 
I use windows 8 and I'm trying to connect my database to Andriod I've created PHP files , but I need somewhere to place these files . my database is located somewhere in my uni server. I've downloaded WAMP server, but it doesn't seem that it work cuz I always get this error

```
( ! ) Warning: mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\wamp\www\test\create.php on line 2
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  669600  {main}( )   ..\create.php:0
2   0.0004  669992  mysql_connect ( )   ..\create.php:2

( ! ) Warning: mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. (trying to connect via tcp://http:3306) in C:\wamp\www\test\create.php on line 2
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  669600  {main}( )   ..\create.php:0
2   0.0004  669992  mysql_connect ( )   ..\create.php:2

( ! ) Warning: mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\wamp\www\test\create.php on line 2
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0004  669600  {main}( )   ..\create.php:0
2   0.0004  669992  mysql_connect ( )   ..\create.php:2
Failed to connect to MySQL:
```

Comment: my database is place in the university server ,my instructor have already created the db   $con=mysql_connect("name.sqldb.univeristy.ac.uk","username","password","myDB");

Comment: <?php
$con=mysql_connect("http://name.sqldb.univeristy.ac.uk","username","password","myDB");

// Check connection
if (mysql_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


?>

Comment: Just a check...is it 'univeristy' or 'university'? You can see if the MySQL server is up by typing this into cmd (a Windows command-line program): `telnet name.sqldb.univeristy.ac.uk 3306`. You should at least get some sort of connection.

Comment: I did what  u said about command line and when I run the command I got black window (cmd) with the title telnet name.sqldb.univeristy.ac.uk

Comment: Hmm. I don't know what else to say, unfortunately. Also, is the name of the host that your professor told you actually 'name.sqldb.univeristy.ac.uk', and if not, are you replacing it with the real one?

Comment: no it the same host name that was given to me by my professor however did u check the code that I post it for connecting to sql .. could u plz check it I'm not sure 100% if it correct I wrote the code using netbean php

Comment: You were correct; the PHP code that you had posted is incorrect (I had assumed it to be correct, even though I'm no longer familiar with mysql_*).

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to use DB

1. Setup your connection in dbconnect.php file (You can take any name)
2. Connect your database by giving correct URL
3. Connect dbconnect.php to your php file

   - You can check your connection in Postman client extension for chrome

You need to reside your database as it is in unix server, you only need to connect correctly it by URL. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you need to select your desired MySQL database in a separate call: [`mysql_select_db`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php). Using the example from that page, we can build this:

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('name.sqldb.univeristy.ac.uk', 'username', 'password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

// Choose a database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('myDB', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Failed to select database: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

---

As an aside, if you are required to use `mysql_*`, then I'd *highly* advise you to learn about PDO. Basically, the `mysql_*` functions are considered deprecated, and are going to be removed in future versions of PHP. There are a few alternatives though, and you can learn more about it [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: thank u ^^, I tried what u posted and I got this error Failed to connect: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. I'm looking at pdo now I will try to use it and check if it will work

Comment: Out of curiousity...are you on campus? You may have to be on the campus network to access the URI; that error message basically says that it couldn't reach 'name.sqldb.univeristy.ac.uk'.